# Direct rendering disabled

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, steam

Originally games lagged a lot so I found out I should switch my driver to one that wasn't open source. I did that through the additional drivers setting and I chose what I believe is the most up-to-date. After that Steam has been giving me an error: "OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering, which may cause performance problems." I looked it up and was told to run the command "glxinfo | grep render" and it told me direct rendering was off. After some research it seemed that the Steam error was common but for most direct rendering was on. That was when I came across this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211206. The two things he removed does not exist for me. I guess it's just an old post. If anyone can help me that'd be great. I've been trying to fix this for hours now and I'm starting to lose courage.

This is where it all began if you're interested. My /r/Ubuntu post: http://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/30adgn/noob_question/

Comment: So you resolved this via installing the proprietary drivers and rebooting, correct?